# xpath exclude element and its parent by child attribute containing a value

Tags: xpath

I wanna get all text except element whose child attribute containing certain value, which I have tried:

```
text ='''<div class="a">
    some text i want to see
    <div1 class="b">
        other text i want to see
        <a class="222">246</a>
    </div1>
    <div1 class="c">
        some text i DON'T WANT to see
        <a class="222">123</a>
    </div1>  
    some more text i wish to see..
</div>'''
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.HTML(text)
print(tree.xpath ('//div[@class="a"][not(../../a[@class="222"])]')[0].xpath('string(.)'))
```

But it did't work.
The output I want to get:
some text i want to see
some more text i wish to see..

Comment: Please tag XPath questions with a version number. There are many things (like this) that are hard to do in XPath 1.0 but very easy in later versions. But sadly, a lot of tools are stuck on XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not *quite* possible to do in XPath 1.0, but it's possible to do something quite close.

You say you want to see the following output:

> some text i want to see some more text i wish to see..

This is a string concatenation of two of the text nodes in the document. I don't think it's possible to return a string containing a concatenation of an arbitrary set of text nodes. If you could identify a certain fixed number of text nodes, you could join them together with the `concat()` function, e.g.

```xpath
concat(
   /div[@class='a']/text()[1], 
   /div/div[@class='b']/text()[1],
   /div[@class='a']/text()[last()]
)
```

... but that's obviously no help in your case. In your case, where you want to use an expression which returns a nodeset containing an arbitrary number of text nodes, there's no function in XPath 1.0 that will concatenate those text nodes into a string. The `string()` function would return a string equal to the *first* text node in the nodeset. In XPath 2.0 the `string-join()` function can be used to do this, but it's not available in XPath 1.0.

So the best you can do is return a set of text nodes, and join them into a string in your host language (Python).

Try this expression:

```xpath
//text()[not(parent::div/a/@class='222')]
```

Meaning: "all text nodes which don't have a parent which is a `div` containing an `a` child with a `class` attribute equal to `222`"